# Merge arrays on Laravel php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

iam passing value 228 to a function in `$admin_id`

```
public function indexAll($admin_id)
    {
        $getids = User::where('ot_of', $admin_id)->pluck('id')->toArray();
        $ids = array_merge($admin_id , $getids);
        dd($ids);
}
```

and in `$getids` have data like this

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => 565
  1 => 823
]
```

but in $ids my result is null any help would be thankfull.
result should be

```
array:2 [▼
      0 => 565
      1 => 823
      2 => 228
    ]
```

Comment: Where is `$subadmin_id` set?

Comment: soryy it is $admin_id

Comment: Ok, `$admin_id` suggests this is an integer, not an array, is it an array?

Comment: `array_merge` is for merging arrays. In order to push an integer, do: `$getids[] = $admin_id;`.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this also

```
public function indexAll($admin_id)
{
    $getids = User::where('ot_of', $admin_id)->pluck('id')->toArray();
    array_push($getids,$admin_id);
    dd($getids);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you named `$admin_id` suggests it is of type `integer`. `array_merge()` is for merging *arrays*. You can achieve this by making `$admin_id` an array:

```
public function indexAll($admin_id)
{
   $getids = User::where('ot_of', $admin_id)->pluck('id')->toArray();
   $ids = array_merge([$admin_id], $getids);
   dd($ids);
}
```